# jQM + WL on Android - High CPU in landscape

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

The current version of my app, running on Android 4.0.4 on an ancient Galaxy Tab has an odd issue when it's running in landscape orientation. I have the CPU usage developer option turned on, and I can see that a single core is being fully utilised when the app is sitting idle, even at it's login screen.

I'm using jQM 1.4.4, WL 6.2.0.01-20141027-1531.

When it's clear that CPU usage idling high for my app, I change to portrait and the CPU usage completely goes away, and the app is responsive again.

**Step (CPU usage after a few seconds)**

- Login Screen (high)
- Tap in text field, keyboard appears (none)
- Hide keyboard (none)
- Switch to portrait (none)
- Switch to landscape (high)

On top of that, when I switch from Portrait to Landscape, the view doesn't redraw under the new aspect. The view is constrained to an area (square-ish) as wide as the screen is tall (or wide in portrait). The fixed header disappears but the view is interactive. To fix this, you can tap into a text field which brings up a keyboard. The view updates to fill the screen, and CPU usage is down again.

Other thing to note is that this issue did not exist in the previous version of the app. I've reviewed all changes between the versions and nothing stands out to me that should cause an issue like this.

Suspects:

- the page or pagecontainer, popup or fixed header is doing a lot of work that usually should only occur on window resize (no direct changes to the logic here);
- the CSS, in particular some responsive queries (there's a breakpoint between landscape and portrait) (no responsive CSS changes)

Other info:

- Not a single problem was reported with Samsung Tab 3 running 4.2.2 or a Nexus 7 on 4.4.4 with this version
- Tried using weinre to profile this issue except it loses connection soon after opening the app (again, previous version it was fine)
- Minor differences between two identical target devices (Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1): one tablet always performs fares better

I'm about to roll back to the older codebase and iteratively add code back in to see where the issue comes in.

Thanks for reading. Any pointers or suggestions are obviously greatly appreciated.

### Update 1

I profiled from within Eclipse (turns out the Timeline inspector tab is pretty useless in weinre).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ke0a9c2z9krhucu/highThreadUsage.PNG

Doesn't mean much to me. I suspect all that profile really says is 'the webview is doing all the work'.

I've created a new Hybrid app in the same project, and copied everything into it. I'm going to start stripping out chunks of code/functionality to see resolves the issues first.

Comment: Could you also try the same w/out Worklight and see if it is happening still. Will help to minimize the possible causes.

Comment: Are you using a custom JQuery version Or relying on the WL provided one?

Comment: @IdanAdar how would I go about removing WL? Just remove all files referenced from worklight/?

Comment: You could either recreate the app as pure web app with jQM (just the UI...). By removing the Worklight references I am not sure how to app will load.

Comment: @AAhad It's regular jQM with all the trimmings (except custom theme)

Comment: I am asking for the JQuery only? not JQM. WL provides a default Jquery version which you are free to NOT use. If you are relying on WL provided JQuery then try to use a regular JQuery in both version of your App i.e. migrated App and non-migrated App. This might be JQuery related issue OR could be CSS issue even.

Comment: @IdanAdar how would I create a 'pure' web app without WL? Create an app with a webview and load it in? The issue only appears on that particular device. Also, there is plenty of WL code that is running when the app loads, so might not be a proper analogue.

Comment: @AAhad ah, my apologies. I'm using jQuery 2.0.2 as it also plays nicely with Windows Store apps (next platform). I'm going to create a shell app and build up from there and see where the issue creeps in.

Comment: In case you try without WL, try to create a simple Crodova App and just dump all your Common folder from WL into it. And must disable the WL App calls in js.  Follow this easy step to create Cordova App http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a preliminary answer. I'm still doing the legwork and trying to see what exactly is happening in this situation.

The culprit appears to be a specific panel. A panel I haven't even touched in weeks. The only thing that I can even think of is that I changed the padding-top on `.ui-tabs-panel` from 1em to 0.5em...

There are two panels that are immediately init'd on app load. The one that slides from the right is the culprit: if I remove the init call and the HTML for it, the app is fine. Putting it all back, and prematurely opening the panel via weinre resolves the issue. Next step, is changing that `padding-top` back to 1em.

Problem doesn't show up. I repeat this several times over: make a build with 0.5em padding, and another with 1em. Repeat. The 0.5em build always has the issue, the other does not.

I'm going to chalk this up to the most coincidental (read: unlucky) bug, ever.

I'm planning on hardcoding the panel contents to `display:none` and showing them when the panel is opened. See if that works.

Comment: Good to know that. As I already pointed out that it would be either JQuery or even CSS issue and nothing with WL. So its CSS issue.